# Memberships engine not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I've installed [RefineryCMS](http://www.refinerycms.com) and a couple of its engines (like Blog). Everything was working fine until I installed Memberships engine.

After struggling a couple of days, I could make it "work". By "work" I mean that I could create a user, but since I have it installed, each time I access the home page I get the following error:

```
undefined method `refinery_user?'
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <% if refinery_user? %>
2:   <% unless admin? # all required JS included by backend. %>
3:     <% content_for :stylesheets, stylesheet_link_tag('refinery/site_bar') unless !!local_assigns[:exclude_css] %>
4:     <%= yield(:stylesheets) unless local_assigns[:head] or local_assigns[:exclude_css] %>
```

I've "ctrl+click" on that method and it does exist!! It has the following code:

```
def refinery_user?
  user_signed_in? && current_user.has_role?(:refinery)
end
```

The weird thing is that I've put a breakpoint on that line but the app didn't stop there...

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `/config/initializers/devise.rb` file exists and that it includes the following (probably at the bottom):

```
config.router_name = :refinery
```